# Which episode does Sakura tell Lady Tsunade to not to overestimate Shikamaru?

Tags: naruto

I am looking for the episode in which Sakura tells Lady Tsunade to not overestimate Shikamaru. In reply, Tsunade tells her that she might have underestimated him and shows her a letter from the feudal lord of the land of fire.

Comment: If your question is answered please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Naruto Shippuden episode 87* shows conversation of Sakura and Tsunade about Shikamaru.